# Como ter várias classes de exceção no Junit do Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Gostaria de ter várias classes de exceção nesse trecho de código abaixo, mas só estou conseguindo colocar uma, como faço para colocar várias classes de exceção?

```
 @Test(expected = NameProjectEmployeeCadastradoException.class)
```

Eu tentei assim, não funcionou;

```
@Test(expected = NameProjectEmployeeCadastradoException.class,  NameProjectCadastradoException.class )
```

Observem o código completo  do java.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})
public class AdicionarProjetoSucessApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;



    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


    @Autowired
    private EmployeeProjectService employeeProjectService;


    @Test(expected = NameProjectEmployeeCadastradoException.class)
    public void testAdicionarProject() throws Exception{
        Project project1 = new Project("Google");
        this.projectService.salvar(project1);
        Assertions.assertThat(project1.getName()).isNotNull();

        Project project2 = new Project("TOTVS");
        this.projectService.salvar(project2);
        Assertions.assertThat(project2.getName()).isNotNull();

        Project project3 = new Project("Microsoft");
        this.projectService.salvar(project3);
        Assertions.assertThat(project3.getName()).isNotNull();

        Project project4 = new Project("TOVOS");
        this.projectService.salvar(project4);
        Assertions.assertThat(project4.getName()).isNotNull();


        Employee employee1 = new Employee("Douglas", BigDecimal.valueOf(16556));
        this.employeeRepository.save(employee1);
        Assertions.assertThat(employee1.getName()).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(employee1.getSalary()).isNotNull();

        Employee employee2 = new Employee("Paulo", BigDecimal.valueOf(16556));
        this.employeeRepository.save(employee2);
        Assertions.assertThat(employee2.getName()).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(employee2.getSalary()).isNotNull();


        Employee employee3 = new Employee("José", BigDecimal.valueOf(16556));
        this.employeeRepository.save(employee3);
        Assertions.assertThat(employee3.getName()).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(employee3.getSalary()).isNotNull();


        Employee employee4 = new Employee("Maria", BigDecimal.valueOf(16556));
        this.employeeRepository.save(employee4);
        Assertions.assertThat(employee4.getName()).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(employee4.getSalary()).isNotNull();


        EmployeeProject employeeProject1 = new EmployeeProject(1, 1);
        this.employeeProjectService.salvar(employeeProject1);
        Assertions.assertThat(employeeProject1.getEmp_id());
        Assertions.assertThat(employeeProject1.getProj_id());

        EmployeeProject employeeProject2 = new EmployeeProject(1, 1);
        this.employeeProjectService.salvar(employeeProject2);
        Assertions.assertThat(employeeProject2.getEmp_id());
        Assertions.assertThat(employeeProject2.getProj_id());


        EmployeeProject employeeProject3 = new EmployeeProject(1, 1);
        this.employeeProjectService.salvar(employeeProject3);
        Assertions.assertThat(employeeProject3.getEmp_id());
        Assertions.assertThat(employeeProject3.getProj_id());

        EmployeeProject employeeProject4 = new EmployeeProject(1, 1);
        this.employeeProjectService.salvar(employeeProject4);
        Assertions.assertThat(employeeProject4.getEmp_id());
        Assertions.assertThat(employeeProject4.getProj_id());

    }

}
```

Comment: Esse parâmetro só suporta 1 exceção. Vejo duas soluções: 1) não usar o `expected` e sim usar `try/catch` dentro do método de teste, dando um `assertTrue` caso a execução caia na exceção (que é o que você quer testar, certo?); 2) criar uma exceção "pai", fazer com que as exceções que você quer testar herdem esse pai e, finalmente, no `expected` você passa essa exceção pai como parâmetro.

Comment: @StatelessDev, forneça uma resposta a partir do seu comentário :)